# Winnerless bounties

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140346/how-do-i-extend-scala-swing) for which I posted a bounty, and, at the end of the allotted time, all answers had score 0. Rightfully, too, as, to this day, no one actually answered the question.

No question was marked as accepted -- thankfully! -- but I can't accept any answer anymore. I also can't open a new bounty on it. Honestly, I don't mind losing the reputation on the bounty permanently, but I do mind not even ever being able to have an accepted answer to my question!

I understand being able to reopen bounty on questions can lead to exploits, but in a case where NO answer was accepted at all, this just doesn't seem to be the correct behavior.

Comment: This is a duplicate several times over

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug / feature.

One which may not be high on their list of fixes.

---

There is a comment on question "[No question marked answered when bounty expired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13133/no-question-marked-answered-when-bounty-expired)"
by one of the people responsible for the site.

---

I **knew** I have seen this brought up before:

["Why an answer can’t be accepted after an unresolved bounty?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty)

Comment: I didn't even think it was classified as a bug, actually.

Comment: Of course it's not high on their list of fixes.  The SO team is siphoning off these lost bounties to bolster their own rep scores.  It's one of the many scams they have going to steal rep from hardworking SO users and line their own rep-hungry pockets.

Comment: **Is not a bug**, feature may be *improved*.

Comment: It's a bug if no answer can be accepted after expiration.