# Bounty Reward Problem

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What happens if there are no answers to a bounty question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/what-happens-if-there-are-no-answers-to-a-bounty-question)
>   [Should bounty be returned if there is NO answer at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21609/should-bounty-be-returned-if-there-is-no-answer-at-all)

I have 'invested' 50 reputation to obtain an answer to a question.

Although I lost my reputation, I didn't receive any answer.
From my point of view, we should not lose reputation if no answer is given. I don't think that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

You may not have gotten an *answer*, but you got 7 days of promotion for your question, which is what the reputation cost of the bounty is for.

Beyond that, https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty --

> First, make sure you've asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

Nobody should be more dedicated to your question than you!