# why should the bounty not refunded if the question has no answer at all?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Having a bounty open, it's almost five days, but I haven't got any answer. But being said that **"All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances."**, neither I am going to get an answer not the bounties back.

Though I have read somewhere in comments, that if there is no risk, everyone would have stared bounties. But isn't it unfair not to get those bounties back for those where there haven't been posted any answers or where none of the answers meets the eligibility criteria? Though you can have bounties disabled for such questions to be started again.

I could have considered deleting the question before starting bounty, but I neither got any comment nor any downvote to indicate if there is a problem with the question.

**PS:** Had I been Jon Skeet, loosing a thousand bounties wouldn't have mattered :)

Comment: If you advertise in a news paper, you also don't get your money back if there are no responses. This is no different. There are no guarantees.

Comment: @Bart It's even worse, newspaper ads cost real money but bounties cost only imaginary Internet points.

Comment: If I don't get all of my imaginary internet points, children are going to starve in Africa!

Comment: I would vote-to-close your bounty question. You already have a benefit from your bounty. I can't do that until the bounty is over.

Comment: @juergend i didn't get you.

Comment: @ay89: Questions that don't fit Stack Overflow can be closed. But bounty questions can't. So your question might already be closed by now if you didn't put a bounty on it.

Comment: @ay89: Besides you would get more attention to your question if you tagged with high viewed tags. In what language do you program? You can tag with that.

Comment: @juergend but i waited for almost a week before starting bounty. Neither I got downvotes nor anyone closed. this left me with no clue whats wrong with the question.

Comment: @juergend it simply belonged to android, and i tagged the same, and android has much follower anyway.

Comment: @ay89: The problem is with your question. It is unclear, you show no code, ...

Comment: I agree with the OP. 
 
I think this is a bad policy. If there's at least 1 answer then maybe we should be forced to award the bounty but if there's no answers then why punish the question asker? It discourages people from setting bounties which is counter productive to the community. I've abandoned CrossValidated for this reason myself.

Comment: It penalizes questions on less popular topics. I've set a bounty and after 2 days, I've only had a handful of additional views. I'm not getting the "extra attention" I "paid" for.  I guess its better to add additional tags that are only peripherally related. That's free.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are "paying" for the extra attention, not for answers.  You got the attention, which was exactly what you paid for.

I would also advise you to consider the possibility that there are problems with your question that make it harder for people to answer it.  Consider taking some time to go over the question (generally several times, if it's important enough for you to bounty) looking for things that might be unclear, lacking in detail, or just not as well written out, or look for information that appears to be overly wordy and not helpful that can be trimmed down.  By improving on the question itself (whether it's bountied or not) can help you get better answers.  In particular pay attention to any comments that would indicate confusing or unclear points in the question that you can consider addressing in edits.

FYI, the above was written without looking at the bounty question.  After looking at the question, it reaffirmed my suspicion that the question is not of good quality, and that is likely contributing to the lack of answers.

Some red flags in your question are the use of "doesn't work".  What does "doesn't work" mean?  What, specifically, does it do, and what should it do instead.  You linked to a related post, but didn't indicate what problems you had using the answer in that question.  Was there a problem with it, was the question itself different (if so, how, and what impact does that difference have).  More detail about what you did try would also help.  After describing the *specific* problems with your solution, you should probably actually *post that solution* rather than just saying you wrote one (although try to ensure you include only what's relevant, don't dump a lot of unrelated code).

Comment: I would have considered revising question had someone commented or downvoted(yes but i got 1) it. If question is not so answerable it should have been closed.

Comment: @ay89 Yes, in my opinion that question should have been closed.  It's unfortunate that it was not.

Comment: you say it's a pity you didn't get advice about how to improve your question - this is one of the benefits of the "attention" a bounty can bring. You've had a number of suggestions now about improving your question - do you feel you've had your bounty's worth now?

Comment: @KateGregory - it was just now when this question appeared here. else it has been 5days already.

Comment: "You are "paying" for the extra attention, not for answers." not really. When you want to start a bounty, you get 6 different options on what you're looking for. One of them is _Draw attention_ but we also have _Canonical answer required_ (A detailed canonical answer is required to adress all the concers)

Comment: @Isa And yet the behavior of all of them is identical, in that it draws additional attention to the post.  You can use that attention to provide a different message, but you're still drawing attention regardless.

Comment: @Servy What's the goal when someone starts a bounty? Users look for an answer. "if you don't get any answers, you absolutely should get your rep back; you've paid for a service that wasn't delivered - that's a refund in anybody's book." [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21609#53700)

Comment: @Isa Your goal when you put up a bounty may be to get an answer, but that's not what you're paying for.  You're paying for attention.  You're not guaranteed to get an answer that you like when you get a bounty; that's not the service that's being provided.  In the same way, if you go to a restaurant, order a meal, and find yourself still hungry, you're not entitled to a refund on the grounds that your goal of filling up wasn't fulfilled.  The service you paid for, a meal, was provided.

Comment: @Servy I think you are in the case where there _was at least an answer given_ (no matter what kind of answer). In that case, I have a different opinion about it (very likely, I'd be against returning the points to OP). But in the case where there was **no** _answer_, then It is as if the waiter had never brought me the food I ordered (I had already paid), waiter only went to took my order and that's it. Never comeback. In that case, I think it would be fair to receive my money back.

Comment: Well, it's a matter of perspective, @Isa.  The network has *never* guaranteed an answer; there's no way you can, short of paying a ton of experts to contribute.  Since we're all volunteers here, the expectation that you are entitled to an answer is misplaced.  Continuing the restaurant analogy, the bounty is like a tip given prior to service; it's supposed to get you better attention, but the server may just end up treating you the same as anyone else.  You get your food when you get your food; a specialized order doesn't always happen.

Comment: @fbueckert I know that nothing guarantees me an answer from any user. And that's fine, I understand. The only thing I would like it to be different, is that the fact of giving the OP its points back in case no one has given an answer was fully supported. This more than anything is because, on some occasions, OP could have a few points. So if OP wanted to put another bounty on another question, maybe it won't be possible anymore.