# What happens if Bounty expires after Seven Days and you have not selected an answer?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Winnerless bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/winnerless-bounties)

What happens if Bounty expires after Seven Days and you have not selected an answer ?

Comment: *Ahem*: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/

Comment: declined in favor of the dupe

Comment: What is declined?

Answer (score 2):

The highest voted answer provided *after the bounty started* will be automatically accepted and receive half the bounty provided it has 2 or more votes.

This is explained in the /faq on each site.

For a more detailed explanation see:

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow)