# bounty questions -no answers after bounty has started- what happens?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Winnerless bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/winnerless-bounties)
>   [What happens if Bounty expires after Seven Days and you have not selected an answer ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26958/what-happens-if-bounty-expires-after-seven-days-and-you-have-not-selected-an-answ)

I had asked a question earlier, got one answer which was not satisfactory. It has one upvote

So I started a bounty and have not got any new answers yet.

This is the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102841/log4net-comparing-adonetappender-and-rollingfileappender).

[SO- bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)  says that

> If there is no answer meeting the
>   above criteria, and you as the
>   question owner have not opted to
>   accept an answer, you forfeit your
>   right to ever accept an answer to your
>   question.

So if I do not accept this answer(which was posted before I started the bounty), **do I lose the right to accept answers for any of my past/future questions ?**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26958/what-happens-if-bounty-expires-after-seven-days-and-you-have-not-selected-an-answ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/winnerless-bounties http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27307/why-do-i-always-have-to-accept-an-answer-at-the-end-of-the-bounty-period

Comment: Black helicopters, man.  Black helicopters is what happens.

Comment: black helicopters ??

Comment: @user you haven't heard of them? I know users that never made it back. And those were the lucky ones.

Comment: Yep, this area of functionality on SO is severley brain-dead.

Answer (score 3):

No, you're just not able to accept answers for this specific question in the future.